# How to easily deploy a Java EE 7 compliant web application from GitHub to the Cloud?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jenkins, openshift, cloudbees, bitnami

I am searching for a solution to deploy a Java EE 7 compliant web application from a public GitHub repository to a cloud service. My application uses a MySQL database and JSF as frontend technology.

I've seen that there are a couple of services that offer Java Hosting in the cloud like OpenShift, CloudBees and bitnami.

I can imagine that the easiest way would be a Jenkins server with a GitHub plugin which automatically checks out the master trunk and deploys the application on a JEE7 application server (like WildFly 8 oder GlassFish 4).

Does anyone have experience with it and already tested a JEE cloud service? I'm looking for recommendations. It should be simple.

Answer (score 1):

With Cloudbees you can easily do that: you can host your JavaEE app, your database and use Jenkins to implement CI.

There are several JAVAEE containers (different versions of Jboss and Glassfish) that you can use, see https://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/ClickStack

The fastest way to get a JavaEE app up and running is to use one of the CloudBees ClickStarts(https://wiki.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/ClickStart, just choose the one closest to your needs- there are many built on JavaEE containers).

Creating and binding a database on cloudbees is really straightforward: https://wiki.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/DatabaseGuide

Also, with Jenkins on Cloudbees, you can configure your job to trigger a build after every commit on github and set a post-build action to deploy the application automatically after a successful build.